# Tangential component of the binormal B vector .

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X_B$ be the tangential component of the binormal vector $B$ of a unit speed curve $\gamma$  on a surface M .

Prove that:

$X_B=-(\frac{\kappa_n}{\kappa})S$

I know that : $X_B=B-<B,n>n.$

Where :
$$ S = n \times T \ \ \ , B=T\times N$$

Comment: If you're going to post questions here, you need to make sure everyone understands your notation. What is $S$? (Some people write that as the shape operator, which clearly makes no sense, since you need a vector here.)

Comment: Sorry .I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**: Take the cross-product with $T$ of the equation $\kappa N = \kappa_n n + \kappa_g S$.